# Asp.net MVC API - Custom Model Routing / Request Transformation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I am creating an Web API application which takes jwt tokens as arguments.

However, I would like to make this transparent to most of the application.

I would like to take a request that looks like:
`website/{controller}/{action}/{token}`

then, parse and verify it, then sending it to the controllers as if it were requested in the following format: `website/{controller}/{action}/user/{sub}/ect/{ect}`

Is there a way for me to implement a catch all transform class in the existing framework? Or will I have to make a transformation method per action?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need a method per action. You can map it to a single controller method that does the routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProfileRoute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{token}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RouteRequest" },
        );
```

This will then map to HomeController.RouteRequest(string token).

Not sure if you can do what you want in the actual route configuration, but I think not.

Comment: while I am sure this could work, this is not much different than using the global.asax to manually process the request

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the token in the header. From wikipedia:

> Whenever the user wants to access a protected route or resource, the
>   user agent should send the JWT, typically in the Authorization header
>   using the Bearer schema. The content of the header might look like the
>   following:
>
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGci......yu5CSpyHI

You can then write a [Authentication Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters) or [custom message handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers) to process the tokens.